# Are unicode identifiers in python bad practice?

Tags: python, unicode, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am getting into machine learning, and to document my code, I will write LaTeX math versions of my functions, right next to the code in an Jupyter/IPython notebook. The mathematical definitions include many Greek symbols, so I thought that I might as well use the Greek symbols in function and variable names, since that's possible in python. Would this be bad practice?

Comment: Do you expect anybody else to want to modify the code? I would consider it impolite to future maintainers to use non-ASCII characters in identifiers. If this is just for you, though, do whatever works for you. Note that Python 2 does not support non-ASCII identifiers.

Comment: This question may be closed as primarily opinion-based... but IMO, code that uses non-ASCII identifiers is not convenient to work with in simple text editors, especially if you don't have the appropriate keymap or compose keys set up.

Comment: @PM2Ring That `__future__` import is for toggling whether or not string literals without a `u` prefix are treated as Unicode or not. There isn't a `__future__` import for toggling whether or not Unicode _identifiers_ are supported in Python 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems a good use case under these assumptions:

- the audience is mathematically versed,
- you make use of a lot of Jupyter Notebook features such as inline plotting and
  table display (e.g. pandas) so that the use of your code outside a notebook
  is unlikely,
- it is application code rather than a library that others will use.

**Hint**:  Entering Greek letters in the notebook is simple. 
Just type the LaTeX math notation and TAB.
For example, type:

```
\pi
```

and then the TAB key to get a π.

Comment: At some point, a person wishes to transfer some notebook code into a module for future reuse, and then non-ascii characters become even a bigger problem.

Comment: Yes, therefore ".. the use of your code outside a notebook is unlikely". Hard to predict the future though. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is what the [official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) has to say:

> For Python 3.0 and beyond, the following policy is prescribed for the
> standard library (see [PEP 3131](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3131/)): All identifiers in the Python
> standard  library MUST use ASCII-only identifiers, and SHOULD use
> English words  wherever feasible (in many cases, abbreviations and
> technical terms are  used which aren't English). In addition, string
> literals and comments  must also be in ASCII. The only exceptions are
> (a) test cases testing  the non-ASCII features, and (b) names of
> authors. Authors whose names  are not based on the latin alphabet MUST
> provide a latin transliteration  of their names.
>
> Open source projects with a global audience are encouraged to adopt a similar policy.

In other words: It would be considered better practice to use ascii-only, if you are targeting a global audience. If the code is only going to be read by your team, it's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

Really, it is a matter of personal opinion. Keep in mind that Unicode character support for variable names is ONLY in Python 3, so make sure that any external libraries support Python 3. Other than that, there isn't a reason to say no.