# Create a multicharacter SymPy symbol for deltax using Greek

Tags: sympy, symbols

I would like to do something like `deltax=symbols(",,\delta x")`
But this seems to give a tuple not a multicharacter symbol. Is it even possible? 
I should add that I am using Jupyter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `symbols` is convenient in that it allows us to create several symbols at once, like `a, b, c = symbols("a,b,c")` or `a, b, c = symbols("a b c")`, or `syms = symbols("a1:6")`. The downside is that we can't use it to create a symbol with a comma (or a space, or a colon) in its name. Instead, the constructor of `Symbol` class has to be used directly:

```
deltax = Symbol(",,\delta x")
```

Comment: How's that? I don't understand. You quoted from my post. So your saying it can't be done generally, or it can?

Comment: In can be done, using the code found on the last line of my answer. Note the difference between `Symbol` and `symbols`.

Answer (score 1):

[Are unicode identifiers in python bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250466/are-unicode-identifiers-in-python-bad-practice)

Contains the answer.
In summary, using Jupyter, \Delta is followed by tab (not space), then x.